# how can I check if sf2utils is properly installed in Python 3.6 on Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound

Python 3.6 comes with Lubuntu 18.04, then I ran pip install sf2utils, it told me installed, but Python script tell me it cannot find it. Can I check wher it is installed